# JQuery disabling button

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, prop

I build a quick pagination from scratch it kind of works, but for the past half hour I've been trying to get the next and/or previous button to disable at the last page like this:
(this one is for the next button)

```
if (currentPage.is(':last-child')) 
{
            $('.paj_next').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.paj_previous').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

here is my code so you can try it out and see what's wrong for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/25/

When you click next it will go too far and not come back

Not exactly sure what's wrong, thanks a bunch in advance. JSFiddle scrambled up my code when I copied it in, sorry for it being so messy!

-Mike

Comment: Problem: `var currentPage = $('.three_paj_els:visible');` Doesn't select a thing when you ran out of things to show. Fix it in the manner suits you.

Comment: OHHH! I fixed it really easily ahaha http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/34/

Comment: @gdoron can you please reply to this as an answer so I can accept the answer? Your comment helped realize my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check whether the nextPage is the last child, than it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/36/

```
    //-------------------------------------NEXT BUTTON
$('.paj_next').click(function() {
    var currentPage = $('.three_paj_els:visible');
    var nextPage = currentPage.next('.three_paj_els');

    if (nextPage.is(':last-child')) {
        $('.paj_next').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.paj_previous').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {

        $('.paj_next').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.paj_previous').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    currentPage.hide();
    nextPage.show();



});
```

Comment: Ohh wow this one works much better than my solution! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

```
var currentPage = $('.three_paj_els:visible');
```

Doesn't select a thing when you ran out of things to show.